# Python: A* routing from dataframe with longitude and latitude

Tags: python, dataframe, latitude-longitude, path-finding, a-star

I have a dataframe with 30,000 records in the following format:

```
ID | Name | Latitude | Longitude | Country |
1  | Hull | 53.744   | -0.3456   | GB      |
```

I would like to select one record to be the start location and one record to be the destination and return a path (list) for the shortest path.

I am using Geopy to find the distance between points in km

```
import geopy.distance

coords_1 = (52.2296756, 21.0122287)
coords_2 = (52.406374, 16.9251681)

print (geopy.distance.vincenty(coords_1, coords_2).km)
```

I have read how to do A* in python from the following tutorial:
https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/implementation.html

However they create a grid system to navigate through.

This is a visual representation of the records in the dataframe:
[image]

This is the code I have so far however it fails to find a path:

```
def calcH(start, end):
    coords_1 = (df['latitude'][start], df['longitude'][start])
    coords_2 = (df['latitude'][end], df['longitude'][end])
    distance = (geopy.distance.vincenty(coords_1, coords_2)).km
    return distance
```

^Calculates the distance between points

```
def getneighbors(startlocation):
    neighborDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Distance'])
    coords_1 = (df['latitude'][startlocation], df['longitude'][startlocation])
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        coords_2 = (df['latitude'][index], df['longitude'][index])
        distance = round((geopy.distance.vincenty(coords_1, coords_2)).km,2)
        neighborDF.loc[len(neighborDF)] = [index, distance]
    neighborDF = neighborDF.sort_values(by=['Distance'])
    neighborDF = neighborDF.reset_index(drop=True)

    return neighborDF[1:5]
```

^Returns the 4 closest locations (ignoring itself)

```
openlist = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'parentID'])
closedlist = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'parentID'])

startIndex = 25479 # Hessle
endIndex = 8262 # Leeds

h = calcH(startIndex, endIndex)
openlist.loc[len(openlist)] = [startIndex,h, 0, h, startIndex]

while True:

#sort the open list by F score
openlist = openlist.sort_values(by=['F'])
openlist = openlist.reset_index(drop=True)

currentLocation = openlist.loc[0]
closedlist.loc[len(closedlist)] = currentLocation
openlist = openlist[openlist.ID != currentLocation.ID]

if currentLocation.ID == endIndex:
    print("Complete")
    break

adjacentLocations = getneighbors(currentLocation.ID)

if(len(adjacentLocations) < 1):
    print("No Neighbors: " + str(currentLocation.ID))
else:
    print(str(len(adjacentLocations)))

for index, row in adjacentLocations.iterrows():
    if adjacentLocations['ID'][index] in closedlist.values:
        continue

    if (adjacentLocations['ID'][index] in openlist.values) == False:

        g = currentLocation.G + calcH(currentLocation.ID, adjacentLocations['ID'][index])
        h = calcH(adjacentLocations['ID'][index], endIndex)
        f = g + h
        openlist.loc[len(openlist)] = [adjacentLocations['ID'][index], f, g, h, currentLocation.ID]
    else:
        adjacentLocationInDF = openlist.loc[openlist['ID'] == adjacentLocations['ID'][index]] #Get location from openlist
        g = currentLocation.G + calcH(currentLocation.ID, adjacentLocations['ID'][index])
        f = g + adjacentLocationInDF.H
        if float(f) < float(adjacentLocationInDF.F):
            openlist = openlist[openlist.ID != currentLocation.ID]
            openlist.loc[len(openlist)] = [adjacentLocations['ID'][index], f, g, adjacentLocationInDF.H, currentLocation.ID]

if (len(openlist)< 1):
    print("No Path")
    break
```

Finds the path from the closed list:

```
# return the path
pathdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'country'])
def getParent(index):

    parentDF = closedlist.loc[closedlist['ID'] == index]
    pathdf.loc[len(pathdf)] = [df['name'][parentDF.ID.values[0]],df['latitude'][parentDF.ID.values[0]],df['longitude'][parentDF.ID.values[0]],df['country'][parentDF.ID.values[0]]]
    if index != startIndex:
        getParent(parentDF.parentID.values[0])

getParent(closedlist['ID'][len(closedlist)-1])
```

Currently this implementation of A* isn't finding a complete path . Any suggestions?

Edit:
I have tried increasing the number of considered neighbors from 4 to 10 and I got a path but not a optimum path:

[image]

We are trying to get from Hessle to Leeds.

[image]
^ available nodes

Raw Data:
[Link](http://viridianforest.co.uk/data/stations.csv)

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem here, but if you only consider the closest 4 other points as neighbors, it is well possible that there will not be a route from start to goal.

Comment: One assumption that I am making is that each point can travel to any other point (4 closest). It does take some time to find the 4 nearest points, but thats an optimization problem for another day. There should always be a path even if its not an optimum one. I think it is because the 4 nearest points exist in the closedlist after a few iterations.

Comment: But what if your start lies within a small cluster of nodes, like what seems to be Ipswich in your map, except with 5 instead of 3 nodes. There will literally be no way out of that cluster. Have you tried lifting the limit to, say, 10 and see what happens, if you still not finding a path?

Comment: Well the algorithm would select the Ipswich node as the start point then search through the 30,000 other nodes to identify the 4 closest nodes and set them as the neighbor and put them into the open list. Then foreach node in the open list it will search the 30,000 nodes for the 4 closest. And it 'should' repeat this process until it finds the end destination. I can try and change it to the 10 nearest neighbors and see if that has any influence. The challenge then is the time it will take to search through the 30,000 nodes repeatedly.

Comment: Or is the algorithm just slow? I haven't used Pandas much, but you should probably use a heap (module `heapq`) for the openlist and a `set` for the closedlist.

Comment: What I meant was: Consider that cluster having 5 nodes instead of just 3. Then the closest 4 nodes to any node within that cluster would still be inside that cluster. But since those clusters are quite rare, that's probably not the problem you are currently facing (but a problem nonetheless IMHO)

Comment: I see what you are saying about the clusters now and perhaps a larger neighbor size would solve that. also It is not just slow, it is failing to find the path and I am not sure if it is my implementation of A* that is the cause

Comment: This could also be a problem for very isolated nodes like Skegness or Cardigan, which seem not to be in the "closest four" for any of the nodes around them.

Comment: Could you add all the available points to the picture showing the path? That might help in understanding why the A* chose some of the more peculiar detours and how to fix it.

Comment: I couldnt draw a direction line on here. But it is going from Hessle to Leeds. It should have gone from Hessle to Ferriby for the first step.

Comment: Okay, as I said, I haven't used Pandas much, but I think this check here `(adjacentLocations['ID'][index] in openlist.values)` (and some similar ones) is wrong. Unless I'm mistaken, this tests whether an index or ID (an `int`) is contained in the list of values, which seem to be the complete lists with index, f, g, h, etc. Those checks would _never_ be true. Thus, the algo would append copies of nodes in the openlist to the openlist, and not skip nodes in the closedlist. But _still_, this should not really matter for A*, expanding best nodes first...

Comment: Those lines of code do seem to work as I added some print statements in each of the IF statements to check if they were being fired.

Comment: Ah, the result of `values` is a 2d numpy matrix, and checking `<int> in ...values` will return true even if the int is not the index but any other int in the matrix (in this case, the index of the parent). Could you try changing those checks to `adjacentLocations['ID'][index] in openlist['ID'].values`?

Comment: It looks like you're overwriting `adjacentLocations` at each loop iteration so that it only contains the points adjacent to the current node being explored instead of points adjacent to anything in the closedlist. This pretty much means you're doing a depth first search, which is why it's sub-optimal. (Also, the indentation in the fifth code block is off)

Comment: @user3080953 Can you explain? As I understand it, `adjacentLocations` is just the neighbors of the current node. All the nodes to visit are stored in `openList`, which is sorted by F in each iteration to get the shortest path, mimicking a (rather slow) heap.

Comment: Oh, are you adding rows from `adjacentLocations` with this line: `openlist.loc[len(openlist)] = [adjacentLocations['ID'][index], f, g, h, currentLocation.ID]`?

Comment: If you are to use the data, perhaps reduce it to just the UK datapoints to make it run faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm still not sure what's the problem with your appraoch, although there certainly are a few, as already mentioned in comments.

- regarding only the closest four (or for that matter, any fixed number of) neighbors might lead to dead-ends or to certain portions of the graph being entirely cut off, e.g. isolated cities that are not within the "closest X" for any of their neighbors
- your checks in the form `x in dataframe.values` will check whether `x` is *any* of the values in the numpy-array returned by `values`, not necessarily the ID field
- using dataframes instead of a proper heap for the open-list and a hash-set for the closed-list makes the search unneccessarily slow, as you have to search and sort the entire lists all the time (not sure whether Pandas can speed up the lookup with indexing, but the sorting definitely takes time)

Anyhow, I found this to be an interesting problem and gave it a try. Turns out, though, that using dataframes as some kind of pseudo-heap was indeed very slow, and also I found the dataframe-indexing to be extremely confusing (and possibly error-prone?), so I changed the code to use [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for data and a proper [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) heap for the `openlist` and a `dict` mapping nodes to their parents for the `closedlist`. Also, there are fewer checks than in your code (e.g. whether a node is already in the openlist) and those do not matter really.

```
import csv, geopy.distance, collections, heapq

Location = collections.namedtuple("Location", "ID name latitude longitude country".split())
data = {}
with open("stations.csv") as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f)
    for d in r:
        i, n, x, y, c = int(d["id"]), d["name"], d["latitude"], d["longitude"], d["country"]
        if c == "GB":
            data[i] = Location(i,n,x,y,c)

def calcH(start, end):
    coords_1 = (data[start].latitude, data[start].longitude)
    coords_2 = (data[end].latitude, data[end].longitude)
    distance = (geopy.distance.vincenty(coords_1, coords_2)).km
    return distance

def getneighbors(startlocation, n=10):
    return sorted(data.values(), key=lambda x: calcH(startlocation, x.ID))[1:n+1]

def getParent(closedlist, index):
    path = []
    while index is not None:
        path.append(index)
        index = closedlist.get(index, None)
    return [data[i] for i in path[::-1]]


startIndex = 25479 # Hessle
endIndex = 8262 # Leeds

Node = collections.namedtuple("Node", "ID F G H parentID".split())

h = calcH(startIndex, endIndex)
openlist = [(h, Node(startIndex, h, 0, h, None))] # heap
closedlist = {} # map visited nodes to parent

while len(openlist) >= 1:
    _, currentLocation = heapq.heappop(openlist)
    print(currentLocation)

    if currentLocation.ID in closedlist:
        continue
    closedlist[currentLocation.ID] = currentLocation.parentID

    if currentLocation.ID == endIndex:
        print("Complete")
        for p in getParent(closedlist, currentLocation.ID):
            print(p)
        break

    for other in getneighbors(currentLocation.ID):
        g = currentLocation.G + calcH(currentLocation.ID, other.ID)
        h = calcH(other.ID, endIndex)
        f = g + h
        heapq.heappush(openlist, (f, Node(other.ID, f, g, h, currentLocation.ID)))
```

This gives me this path from Hessle to Leeds, which seems more reasonable:

```
Location(ID=25479, name='Hessle', latitude='53.717567', longitude='-0.442169', country='GB')
Location(ID=8166, name='Brough', latitude='53.726452', longitude='-0.578255', country='GB')
Location(ID=25208, name='Eastrington', latitude='53.75481', longitude='-0.786612', country='GB')
Location(ID=25525, name='Howden', latitude='53.764526', longitude='-0.86068', country='GB')
Location(ID=7780, name='Selby', latitude='53.78336', longitude='-1.06355', country='GB')
Location(ID=26157, name='Sherburn-In-Elmet', latitude='53.797142', longitude='-1.23176', country='GB')
Location(ID=25308, name='Garforth Station', latitude='53.796211', longitude='-1.382083', country='GB')
Location(ID=8262, name='Leeds', latitude='53.795158', longitude='-1.549089', country='GB')
```

Even if you can't use this because you *have to* use Pandas (?), maybe this helps you finally spot your actual error.

Comment: This has solved it, thank you. I didnt know about heapq before I started or how to map it with a dictionary. But this works and its not even that slow with the whole dataset (not just UK). 
I have to wait 16hours to give you the bounty but thanks again :)